# Only receiving one byte from socket

Tags: python, sockets, socketserver

I coded a server program using python.

I'm trying to get a string but i got only a character!
How can I receive a string?

```
def handleclient(connection):                                           
    while True:                             
        rec = connection.recv(200)
        if rec == "help": #when I put help in the client program, rec = 'h' and not to "help"
            connection.send("Help Menu!")


    connection.send(rec)
    connection.close()

def main():
   while True:
        connection, addr = sckobj.accept()   
        connection.send("Hello\n\r")
        connection.send("Message: ")   
        IpClient = addr[0]
        print 'Server was connected by :',IpClient


        thread.start_new(handleclient, (connection,))
```

Comment: Are you using non-blocking sockets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With TCP/IP connections your message can be fragmented. It might send one letter at a time, or it might send the whole lot at once - you can never be sure.

Your programs needs to be able to handle this fragmentation. Either use a fixed length packet (so you always read X bytes) or send the length of the data at the start of each packet. If you are only sending ASCII letters, you can also use a specific character (eg `\n`) to mark the end of transmission. In this case you would read until the message contains a `\n`.

`recv(200)` isn't guaranteed to receive 200 bytes - 200 is just the maximum.

This is an example of how your server could look:

```
rec = ""
while True:
    rec += connection.recv(1024)
    rec_end = rec.find('\n')
    if rec_end != -1:
        data = rec[:rec_end]

        # Do whatever you want with data here

        rec = rec[rec_end+1:]
```

Comment: so I need to make a loop that will check if the data I recieve equal to \n then check check for "help".

Comment: As I said, you can do it a few ways. If your message will never contain `\n` you can use it as a terminator. Send it at the end of your message in the client, and in the server read data until you see `\n`. I added some quick sample code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solve for stupid embarcadero C++ Builder

```
char RecvBuffer[4096];
boolean first_init_flag = true;
while(true)
{
    int bytesReceived;

    while(true)
    {
        ZeroMemory(RecvBuffer, 4096);
        bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket,(char*) &RecvBuffer, sizeof(RecvBuffer), 0);
        std::cout << "RecvBuffer: " << RecvBuffer << std::endl;
        std::cout << "bytesReceived: " << bytesReceived <<std ::endl;

        if (!std::strcmp(RecvBuffer, "\r\n"))
        {
            if (first_init_flag) {
                first_init_flag = !first_init_flag;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Client disconnected" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    send(clientSocket, RecvBuffer, bytesReceived + 1, 0);
}
```

Firstly, you send \r\n or ENTER for escape concatenating handshake and first data sending